# Initialize dynamically added JQuery Mobile rangeslider

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I am dynamically loading html content using ajax and am having difficulty creating or refreshing the JQuery Mobile rangeslider which is in the content.

HTML

```
 <div class="ui-grid-b ui-responsive">
  <div id="adv-search" data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed-icon="carat-d" data-expanded-icon="carat-u" data-iconpos="right" class="ui-mini">
    <h4>Advanced Search</h4>
    <div class="advanced-search">
     <!--content should get loaded here -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

the closest I can get to having it display correctly is using this line:

```
$(document).on("collapsibleexpand", "#adv-search", function() {
    /*make ajax call and on success do this - */
    $(".advanced-search").html(content);
    $("#priceslider").rangeslider();
});
```

but then the problem is that it makes the two range input's look like flip switches or mini range sliders instead of proper textboxes (like they should look).

Here is an [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kegt2n9n/31/) with everything I have tried and the result I am getting.

Comment: Use `.enhanceWithin()` to initialize all widgets within container. `$(".advanced-search").html(content).enhanceWithin();` https://jsfiddle.net/kegt2n9n/32/

Comment: Thanks Omar, that did the trick.

Comment: I am sorry for contacting you this way (my comment isnt related to your input here). I came across a question you voted on in "triage" where you made the wrong choice. Please: study the help for triage carefully, to avoid putting items into the edit queue that don't belong there. I hope you see this as a chance to improve your voting. I am specifically talking about https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21156904. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me. If you give me a short heads up, I will quickly delete this comment.